# display pdf in specific jsp page from servlet

Tags: jsp, pdf, servlets, pdf-generation

In my servlet, after doing some operations, I'm generating a PDF. Its in ByteArray.

I'm able to display that PDF in browser by doing,

1. Taking `byte[]` to `InputStream`
2. Writing it to `ByteArrayOutputStream`
3. Then writing `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `ServletOutputStream`.
4. And then return null;

This will display the PDF in my current window, but Is it possible to display PDF in any specific JSP page ? 
Because I want to put some buttons in the footer of that JSP at the same time while displaying pdf. In above way, whole window contains only PDF.

Comment: If your content type is `application/pdf` then What is the use of using specific JSP ?

Comment: Why don't you just write `byte[]` to `ServletOutputStream` directly? `response.getOutputStream().write(bytes)`.

Comment: @HardikMishra I wanted to display PDF in particular part of my JSP. Then user can download it if they want. I did not want to provide only download.

Comment: @HardikMishra By the way, the functionality which I want is supported by only IE as a default behavior. Firefox directly prompts for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed an [`IFRAME`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) in your JSP page and set its dimensions to occupy the entire page except for the portion where you want to display the footer, and the footer would be part of your JSP. The IFRAME target/src would be the servlet that displays the PDF.

Currently, you seem to be calling Servlet B from page A with some request parameters. You should call the new JSP from Page A with the same request parameters, and JSP page would build the target URL for the IFRAME and invokes servlet B which will process and return the PDF page.

Comment: Ok but I am confused at a point that how can I decide that I am forwarding my request to this particular JSP. Here I can just return null.

Comment: Great solution @Vikdor, It worked perfectly as I want. But I've designed the flow like - My jsp will call servlet as it was calling. Then I set the byte[] in session. Now Servlet will forward the request to another jsp. And that jsp will be having iFrame so it will display the pdf. - by checking attrib null or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSP Form Submit
action="PDFServlet" method="post" 
SERVLET code
that reads from byte[] to ServletOutputStream
```

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        File file = new File("estatement.pdf");

        ServletOutputStream stream = null;
        BufferedInputStream buf = null;
        try {
            stream = response.getOutputStream();
            // set response headers
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "inline; filename=estatement.pdf");
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            int readBytes = 0;
            while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1)
                stream.write(readBytes);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            if (buf != null)
                buf.close();
        }
    }
```